# Entreprise library caching configuration without configuration file

Tags: caching, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise Library Caching block without configuration  file. Cache settings are initialized from my code. I initialize the cache with the following code:

```
static class LocalCache
    {
        private static readonly CacheManager CacheManager;

        static LocalCache()
        {
            try
            {
                string localCacheName = "MyCache";

                DictionaryConfigurationSource configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
                CacheManagerSettings cacheSettings = new CacheManagerSettings();

                configSource.Add(CacheManagerSettings.SectionName, cacheSettings);
                CacheStorageData storageConfig = new CacheStorageData("NoStorage", typeof(NullBackingStore));
                cacheSettings.BackingStores.Add(storageConfig);

                var expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds = 2;
                CacheManagerData cacheManagerData = new CacheManagerData(
                    localCacheName, 
                    expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds, 
                    100, 
                    20, 
                    storageConfig.Name
                    );
                cacheSettings.CacheManagers.Add(cacheManagerData);
                cacheSettings.DefaultCacheManager = cacheManagerData.Name;

                CacheManagerFactory cacheFactory = new CacheManagerFactory(configSource);
                CacheManager = cacheFactory.CreateDefault();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        public static T GetData<T>(string cacheKey)
        {
            var value = CacheManager.GetData(cacheKey);
            return (T)value;
        }

        public static void AddData(string cacheKey, object value)
        {
            CacheManager.Add(cacheKey, value);                
        }
    }
```

The issue is that the `expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds` (here 2 seconds) is not taken into account when retrieving a cache item that is supposed to be expired. The item reside in cache longer than 2 seconds.
Any idea ?

See test example below:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            LocalCache.AddData("One", 1);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            LocalCache.AddData("Two", 2);

            object data = LocalCache.GetData<object>("One");

            if (data == null) Console.WriteLine("Data not in cache");
            else Console.WriteLine("-----> Data in cache whereas it should not !!!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
-----> Data in cache whereas it should not !!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the online documentation for CacheManagerData class, the constructor doesn't take in a cache experts duration period. Instead the second argument is the time period after which the manager will check if the cached items are to be removed if there are too many items.

So, 2 seconds is not the cache expiry.

Whether there are too many items is dependant on the third argument.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee779632.aspx

If you wish to add an expiry period, then have a look at the following:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51409/Exploring-Caching-Using-Caching-Application-Enterp#heading0016